# Exposing identity using SAML to third party

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, single-sign-on, windows-server-2012, saml-2.0

I have created a application with single sign on(ASP.NET application). Now that application needs to provide identity mechanism to some PHP application using SAML security token.

We have both LDAP server & ADFS server service installed on server where application is hosted & can expose ADFS identity metadata xml.

I am blank what I need to expose(service/endpoint/API) & how they will consume that identity.

Any out-of-box solution for this kind of situation

**EDIT** one more case is there where users are non-AD users & need to provide SAML security token in case of non AD users stored in DB also.

Any minor help or links or direction will also help too in great way.

Comment: If the user directly interacts with the PHP application that application needs to become a SAML Service Provider (e.g. using simpleSAMLphp .. https://simplesamlphp.org/) and your app does not need to do anything

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr, Thanks for input, this is just I am looking for. But they don't want to make code changes for authentication. They need some API that will take username & password and return SAML security token. I can find user & can authenticate password then what to do?

Comment: One more case is to provide SAML security token in case of non AD users stored in DB also.

Comment: How Authentication is done in detail is out of SAML spec. The Identity Provider has to perform authentication.

Comment: If they don't want to change anything how could they consume a SAML authentication response issued by a SAML IdP